# python save output line to a new file 

Tags: python

i want to using python create filter for a log file. get recent 7 days record.
but when i didn't know how to compare time.
like current time is 11/9/2012, i want to get records from 04/9/2012 to now

the log file like

```
 Sat Sep  2 03:32:13 2012 [pid 12461] CONNECT: Client "66.249.68.236"
 Sat Sep  2 03:32:13 2012 [pid 12460] [ftp] OK LOGIN: Client "66.249.68.236", anon     password "gxxglxxxxt@google.com"
 Sat Sep  2 03:32:14 2012 [pid 12462] [ftp] OK DOWNLOAD: Client "66.249.68.236",   "/pub/10.5524/100001_101000/100022/readme.txt", 451
```

i using this one

```
  def OnlyRecent(line):
       print time.strptime(line.split("[")[0].strip(),"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
       print time.time()
    if  time.strptime(line.split("[")[0].strip(),"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y") < time.time():
        return True
    return False
```

But it shows

```
   (2012, 9, 2, 3, 32, 13, 5, 246, -1) 
    1347332968.08
   (2012, 9, 2, 3, 32, 13, 5, 246, -1)
    1347332968.08
   (2012, 9, 2, 3, 32, 14, 5, 246, -1)
    1347332968.08
```

after select many lines, how can i create new file(*.txt or log) to store those in script, the file name use current date

Thanks

Comment: I answered this on your earlier question too. Follow the links of the documentations on my answer. That will help you

Comment: @HimanshuJindal, thanks, how can i get before 7 days records start from now

Comment: I think you're overly quick to accept an answer. There are lots of different ways to do this.

Comment: @HimanshuJindal, after select many lines, how can i create new file to store those in script

Answer (score 1):

you can use time.mktime  to convert a time tuple to unix timestamp .

```
>>> import time
>>> time.mktime((2012, 9, 2, 3, 32, 13, 5, 246, -1))
1346527933.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use datetime.datetime.strptime and datetime.datetime.now() to use the same data structure:

```
from datetime import datetime 
def OnlyRecent(line):
  return  datetime.strptime(line.split("[")[0].strip(),"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y") < datetime.now()
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `time` use `datetime` and `timedelta`.

```
seven_days = datetime.timedelta(days=7)

def OnlyRecent(line):
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(line.split('[')[0].strip(), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
    return dt > datetime.datetime.now() - seven_days
```